# My array doesn't get the content of the database

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I want to have an array with the Strings of the result of my Query and the array doesn't add any value. I've already typed my query on my database and it works.

```
public String[] query() {

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/repaso?" + "user=root&password=");

        Statement sentence = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet result = sentence.executeQuery("select marca from marca");

        result.last();
        int i = result.getRow();
        result.beforeFirst();
        System.out.println(result);
        int x = 0;

        String[] array = new String[i];

        while (result.next()) {

            array[x] = result.getString(1);
            x++;

        }
        result.close();

        return array;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e1) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Start by at least printing your exceptions. **Ignoring** errors doesn't getting you to  correct code!

Comment: Then: also print the strings you read from the database. If you dont what your code is doing, then heck: let it print what it is doing to you.